# C++ output producing random long integers

Tags: c++

I recently coded a question, and I have debugged and figured out where the problem is but cannot quite place a finger on it. My program aims to merge groups of sectors if they overlap or are next to each other, but the last section is scrambling the output.

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
freopen("beachin.txt", "r", stdin);
freopen("beachout.txt", "w", stdout);

int n, u, k, x;
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &n, &u, &k, &x);
int umbrellas[u][2];
for (int i = 0; i < u; i++) {
    scanf("%d %d", &umbrellas[i][0], &umbrellas[i][1]);
}

int groups[u][2];
int len = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < u; i++) {
    int s1 = umbrellas[i][0];
    int e1 = umbrellas[i][1];
    int found = false;
    for (int a = 0; a < len; a++) {
        int s2 = groups[a][0];
        int e2 = groups[a][1];
        if ((s1 <= e2 && s1 >= s2) || (e1 >= s2 && e1 <= e2) || (s1 <= s2 && e1 >= e2)) {
            int start, end;
            if (s1 < s2) start = s1;
            else start = s2;
            if (e1 > e2) end = e1;
            else end = e2;
            groups[a][0] = start;
            groups[a][1] = end;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (found == false) {
        len++;
        groups[len][0] = s1;
        groups[len][1] = e1;
    }
}

int largest = 0; // scramble bit here from for loop
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    int current = groups[i][1]-groups[i][0]+1;
    if (current >= largest) largest = current;
}


printf("%d\n", largest);
return 0;
}
```

My input for this is

```
7 2 5 2
4 5
5 6
```

The expected answer is `2`, but the output varies between `2` and random long numbers like `1550870207`.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Note: If it's any help, problem statement is [here](https://orac2.info/problem/aio20beach/)

Comment: please post a [mcve] and explain what the code is supposed to do in more details, provide example input and expected and actual output

Comment: Where is a working example? It's unclear what input and output are\must be. Note, that `int groups[u][2]` is already a red flag unless `u` is a constant. Len is incremented and may become larger than u, by the way

Comment: `scramble` as used in the tag description is about intentionally making information unintelligible. If thats what you do then it is totally unclear what the issue is. If you mean "scramble" as in "not the output I want and I dont understand the output" then the tag is offtopic

Comment: You don't initialize `groups`, and then you read from it first thing. This has undefined behaviour.

Comment: BTW: the only things that are specifically C++ are the first two lines. I would recommend that you learn some C++.

Comment: Side note: Why use `printf`, `scanf` and other C functions for C++?

Comment: `int s2 = groups[a][0];` and the next line invoke undefined behavior. And `int groups[u][2];` is not standard C++

Comment: Which C functions? I've been using this type of code for a few years and no errors occurred :|

Comment: Replace the first 2 lines with `#include <stdio.h>` and you have C code. Forget everything you learned about C and learn C++ from scratch.

Comment: There are two hard problems in computer science: naming things, cache invalidation, and off-by-one errors.  The OP's program suffers from 2 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing out some issues with the code above, many of which you can get reported by using compiler options:

- `umbrellas[u][2]` and `groups[u][2]`: these are variable length arrays; they're not standard C++.
- `n`, `k`, and `x` are declared, read from, but never used later on.
- `groups` is 1) not initialized, 2) filled only for `groups[1]`, so that `groups[0]` values remain undefined (at `if (found == false)` block), and 3) accessed both for `groups[0]` and `groups[1]` (at bottom `for` loop).
- `len` is incremented before being used; in the second iteration of the top `for` loop, the `if (found == false)` loop is executed twice, so the second time you access `groups[2]`; that's an out of bounds access.

Check it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YcT3zG86h). I've modified your code initializing `umbrellas` at the point of declaration, and using fixed length arrays for `umbrellas` and `groups`.

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
    int umbrellas[2][2]{ { 4, 5 }, { 5, 6 } };

    int groups[2][2]{};
    int len{};
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        fmt::print("*** i = {}\n", i);
        int s1 = umbrellas[i][0];
        int e1 = umbrellas[i][1];
        bool found{ false };
        for (int a = 0; a < len; a++) {
            int s2 = groups[a][0];
            int e2 = groups[a][1];

            if ((s1 <= e2 && s1 >= s2) ||
                (e1 >= s2 && e1 <= e2) ||
                (s1 <= s2 && e1 >= e2)) {

                int start{ (s1 < s2) ? s1 : s2 };
                int end{ (e1 > e2) ? e1 : e2 };
                groups[a][0] = start;
                groups[a][1] = end;
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (not found) {
            len++;
            fmt::print("\tAccessing groups[{}]\n", len);
            groups[len][0] = s1;
            groups[len][1] = e1;
        }
    }

    int largest = 0;  // scramble bit here from for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int current = groups[i][1] - groups[i][0] + 1;
        if (current >= largest) {
            largest = current;
        }
    }
    fmt::print("==> largest = {}\n", largest);
}

// Outputs:
//
//   *** i = 0
//      Accessing groups[1]
//   *** i = 1
//      Accessing groups[2]
//   ==> largest = 2
```